# query count id where 2 records condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to display some information from my table

> Table
>
> [image]

I want to count `idxdaftar` where this have kode with value only **1** 
or I want to count `idxdaftar` where this have kode with value **1** and **2**

for example
1) the result count(idxdaftar) where kode with value only **1** = **1**
2) the result count(idxdaftar) where kode with value **1** and **2** = **1**
Help me, please...

Comment: Please be more clear, what output do you need?

Comment: Please see Rahul's answer for the general approach, an my comment there for your specific situation (if I got it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific about the logic behind it but in you can use conditional count using `CASE` expression like

```
sum(case when kode = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: And if I understand correctly:
`sum(case when kode = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ones,
sum(case when kode = 1 or kode = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ones_or_twos`

Comment: @YooHanNeskent, though you edited but your logic makes little sense. Why count(kode = 1)? with respect to what?

Comment: yes I Just Want to calculate how the results count () of idxdaftar which have value only code = '1' not '2'
at other times I want to count how many results count () of idxdaftar which have value only code = '1' and '2'

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, try

```
select type, count(*) 
from (
    select idxdaftar, case when count(distinct kode) = count(distinct case when kode = 1 then kode end) then '1' else '1+2' end type
    from (
        select 50 idxdaftar, 1 kode
        union all
        select 51 idxdaftar, 1 kode
        union all
        select 50 idxdaftar, 2 kode

        ) tab
    group by idxdaftar
    having count(distinct kode) in ( 
           count(distinct case when kode = 1 then kode end),
           count(distinct case when kode in (1,2) then kode end))

) t
group by type
```

Comment: please help me specific :) this is my table name  t_tindakanrajal(idxdaftar int,kode int)      hide idxurut and kategori

Comment: yeah its my goal... but idxdaftar and kode is dynamic record and value

Comment: Not sure I understand which dynamic is requiered. If the query answers the question you may wish to accept it to show others it's correct and ask another question on dynamic you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select count(distinct case when kcode in (1, 2) then idxafter end)
from t;
```